# MVC 3 connection string to Sql Server 2008 R2 cannot connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have the MvcMovie project and have simply aadded a connection string to get to my Sql Server 2008 R2 version for a class called Articles.

I get the error.

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. Inner
>   Exception: {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)"}

All I have added to the project is 
1. a connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ArticleDB" connectionString="Data Source=Home-PC\SqlServer2008;initial catalog=DairyPump3;integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

1. A class called Article

   ```
   public class Article
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Menu { get; set; }
       public string Page { get; set; }
       //public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       //public decimal Price { get; set; }
   }

   public class ArticleDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public ArticleDBContext() : base("ArticleDB") { }

       public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. A ArticlesController referencing EF etc

I have Sql Server tcp and pipes enabled etc, and I allow remote connections. I have tried with creating the db first and then deleting it - but no difference.
I am not using Code First to my knowledge - at least I do not want to use code first.
The app runs for the MvcMusic side but the config file has no connection string for this - I don't know where it stores the music data.

I have googled this and many people have encountered the issue, but their solutions do not seem to address this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor overload you're using is to specify the connection string ("Data source=...") or the database name at the default SQL instance (e.g. "Initial Catalog=**ArticleDb**").

If you name your connection string to `ArticleDBContext` (or your context to `ArticleDB`), it should use the connection string you've specified, and you don't need the constructor either.

Note: I did a quick confirmation of this using EF CF with migrations.  When I used `: base("foo")` I saw a new database named foo come up on .\SQLEXPRESS (the default instance used by EF).  My observations also seem to be confirmed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/09/02/ef-feature-ctp4-dbcontext-and-databases.aspx).

[edit:] Also worth pointing out: when I used the constructor (with `: base("foo)"`), it overrode the settings I had in web.config.  Probably not something you want to do if you're deploying to a server where you need to configure the connection string.

Comment: I tried this - I changed connection string to ArticleDBContext and the constructor to ArticleDBContext i.e. public ArticleDBContext() : base("ArticleDBContext") { } and alos removed the whole constructor - but none of those changed the error message. Is it becasue it is Sql Server 2008. PS I have the DB created. Do I need to delete it?

Comment: Is your install of SQL Server a named instance?  How do you normally connect to SQL?

Comment: Yes it is =- my machine is called Home-PC and my instance is SqlServer2008. I have used this in other .net Visual Studio 2010 projects, but not an MVC one. The connection string I used before was <add name="ArticleDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Home-PC\SqlServer2008;initial catalog=curriculum;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/> but this returns the same error in the MVC project

Comment: P.S. in fact the whole instance name is Home-PC\SqlServer2008

Comment: Can your other apps still connect fine now?  It almost makes me thing that the SQL Server service isn't running or something.

Comment: Apologies - a service was not turned on - despite being able to access it in the Sql Server Management console etc , I guessed this when a power cut caused non access issue to Express as well. Thanks.

Comment: How can I set this as the answer?